# What happened to Kim Soon-Lee?

Tags: the-breaker

How come after chapter 1.5 there is no mention of Kim-Soon-Lee and the operation to catch the Murim killer? Is this due to it being a bonus/filler chapter or has it not yet been covered?

Comment: That chapter is actually chapter 9.5, part of an extra in volume one. the extra chapter are probably considered a side story of the original storyline.

Comment: Chapter 19.5 is the 2nd part of this story, it's in volume 3.

Comment: She appears later in the main story again, not just in the two side story chapters.